# Need help about understand api, wp, $ syntax in WordPress plugin script

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, jquery

I really new in Wordpress development and have a little bit of knowledge of jquery.
I was trying to understand a WordPress plugin and also trying to understand the js code they wrote for the plugin.
I don't understand what does the following code mean.

```
(function( api, wp, $ ) {
'use strict';

})( wp.customize, wp, jQuery );
```

what is **api** , **wp** and **$** at the top and **wp.customize** , **wp** , **jQuery** at the bottom mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) - an anonymous function that executes itself after it has been defined.
The variables at the bottom are taken from the global scope and are passed as parameters to the anonymous function.

So `api` represents `wp.customize`,
`wp` represents `wp` and
`$` represents `jQuery` inside the function.

Comment: Thank you @kwellmann .

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, this function just tells you that strict mode (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp) is being used for the execution of jQuery Scripts of your WordPress customizer. api here just refers to the "connection" onto a specific part, which in this case is the wordpress customizer (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/).

Comment: whoever downvoted my answer may inform me about the reason please, such that I can improve my work.

Comment: @xs-dev Do you know what an API and strict mode in JavaScript coding are? If not, you may specify this in your question.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your answer but your answer is not the answer I'm looking for. I just want to know what api, wp, $ do here. Thanks

Comment: Well as described in my answer, api here corresponds to the wp.customizer API linked above, and $ to the type of code concerned by the function, and wp to wordpress. So, for the execution of jquery in your customizer in wp (wordpress), strict mode is being used. At least that's what I assume, and if true I don't get in which measure that does not answer your question..?